# Jest spyon works when 'require' mocked module and doesn't work when 'import'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jestjs, iframe-resizer

I want to test that my third-party-library ([iframe-resizer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iframe-resizer)) function is called.
My test

```
import React from 'react';
import { fireEvent, render } from 'react-testing-library';
//import  * as depModule from 'iframe-resizer';
let depModule = require("iframe-resizer")
import { MyComponent } from '../my-component';

describe('Component', () => {
   describe('Functional', () => {
     it('should initialize iframeresizer when the iframe has loaded', async 
  () => {
      const iframeResizerMock = jest.spyOn(depModule, "iframeResizer");
      const { queryByTestId } = render(<MyComponent  />);
      fireEvent.load(queryByTestId('csb-iframe'));
      expect(iframeResizerMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
     });
  });
});
```

So the iframeResizer function is called,it was tested by console.log.The strange thing here is when I use

```
import  * as depModule from 'iframe-resizer';
```

The spyon doesn't work(test fails)

But when I use

```
let depModule = require("iframe-resizer")
```

Everything works great(test passes) . I'm new in jest and node modules,so may be I missed simething obvious?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because jest's mocking only works for commonjs modules, and in your case `iframe-resizer` does not ship commonjs modules, and jest does not transform node modules to commonjs.

Take a look at [this thread](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6229). There are many interesting solutions in there.